# CNN model overfitting to a Color, not learning edges

Tags: keras, cnn, object-detection

I've been working on this binary classifier which predicts if a certain type of battery is in the live webcam feed or not. The problem I am facing is that my CNN model predicts any 'orange object' in the frame as a battery. It can't tell the difference between an orange pair of scissors and a cuboidal orange battery. Also, sometimes it detects a human as a battery too.

Battery Image: 
https://robu.in/product/orange-5200mah-3s-40c80c-lithium-polymer-battery-pack-lipo/

I've tried several CNNs like,
A) Classic CNN with ~10 layers (3x(Conv2D, MaxPooling), 2xDense along with a few BatchNormalization and Dropout layers) *--Validation Accuracy ~92%*
B) **Concatenation of two NN (1. using canny edge filter on my complete dataset 2. With the colored images)**  *--Validation accuracy <67.66%*
C) MobileNet on Colored Images
D) ResNet
E) AlexNet
etc...

I've tried Data Augmentation(Using Grayscale images, Adding/Subtracting Pixel values, etc.)

All images are of size 150×150 Total image dataset of ~200 images

How should I tackle this problem of color overfitting?

Comment: do you have non battery objects in your data set or just batteries, also could you not just implement the model in a situation where there will be no other objects (against a white sheet of paper for instance)

Comment: Maybe you can try Anomaly Detection. It means that we will train the model only on battery images. As soon as it will see an image which is not a battery, the classification loss will increase which can be treated as an anomaly.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal How do I apply this to my CNN? I can't understand how does this differ from my current approach of training my CNN on battery images(different angles, different background, different lighting conditions) and non battery images(same background without the battery, random objects).

Comment: How many examples of the battery do you have? How many examples of the false positive for battery do you have? 200 is likely too low.